# Is there a way to export files during a docker build?

Tags: docker

I do a multistage build right now. The first stage compiles with credentials for my internal repos and I just keep the binaries as per this example: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md

But I want to run in CI server and need to provider the CI server with test and coverage reports. It would be most elegant to do this in the build layer but how do I get files *out* of a docker image during build?

For example:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build

WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj .
COPY ./nuget.config .
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy and publish app and libraries
COPY . .

############ Get this files out #####################
# Generate test report. copy this to external directory
RUN dotnet test --logger trx
# Generate coverage report. copy this to external directory
RUN dotCover.sh dotnet --output=myRep.html --reportType=HTML -- test
#######################################################

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out  --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app/
COPY --from=build /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnetapp.dll"]
```

So I want to be able to run docker build and have it dump a test and coverage report to the current directory where docker build command was run. Is this possible? It would make this seamless for CI because all server must do is run docker build and it get reports

Comment: You probably want to hook up a docker volume for the container to dump the reports to for later review. What CI/CD setup are you using?

Comment: what about this https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#custom-build-outputs. I would be hard to dynamically mount in the CI server

Comment: The docker output command is for the output directly of the `image` and not the results of any processing that takes place within a `container`. This allows you, for instance, to send a docker image file via other means!

Comment: I wouldn't run either of these commands in the Dockerfile, and probably wouldn't run them in Docker at all.  Have your CI system run the unit tests itself and collect the resulting artifacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker build` supports an `--output` flag. I *think* it requires BuildKit (`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`). [Here's one example usage.](https://github.com/aporia-ai/TrainInvaders/blob/main/Makefile#L31)

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/ - then find `--output` on the page
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#output